# OutOfMemory Exception in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am running JMeter test on machine having 12 GB RAM but I am getting 'OutOfMemory: Heap Space' exception while running the test for 100 users only.

My script has around 300 http requests and is of sync with server scenario.

I have already increased the max heap to 8 GB and tried running the test in Non-GUI mode after disabling all the listeners.

Moreover, I have other script of same application and they are working fine with 200 users load.

Can anyone suggest the changes that I need to do in JMeter for running sync script successfully for 200 users.

Comment: can you show your test plan? did you try to increase the ramp up?

Comment: No plan, no actual exception, no screenshot of the running java process settings...

Answer (score 0):

As you do not provide much details, it is very hard to answer but check:

- that you're not running in GUI mode with View Results Tree as it is an Anti-Practice, if it's the case use NON GUI mode:

  - https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/
  - http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices
- in jmeter.log that the allocated heap is really what you think
- that you have not allocated as much heap as you have RAM, you need to give some memory to the OS (300 MB)
- That you're running last jmeter version and not an old one